# Log File Rotation IOException

Tags: c#, .net, file, logging, file-io

I've got a log file rotation function that looks like this:

```
    private static void RotateLogs()
    {
        FileInfo LogFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\dataTransferErrorLog.txt");

        if (LogFile.Exists && (LogFile.Length) >= 10 * 1048576)
        {
            Compress(LogFile);
            LogFile.Delete();
            File.Create(@"C:\temp\dataTransferErrorLog.txt");
        }
    }

    private static void Compress(FileInfo fi)
    {
        // Get the stream of the source file.
        using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            // Prevent compressing hidden and 
            // already compressed files.
            if ((File.GetAttributes(fi.FullName)
                & FileAttributes.Hidden)
                != FileAttributes.Hidden & fi.Extension != ".gz")
            {
                string destFileName = fi.FullName.Substring(0, fi.FullName.LastIndexOf('.')) + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + fi.FullName.Substring(fi.FullName.LastIndexOf('.')) + ".gz";
                // Create the compressed file.
                using (FileStream outFile =
                            File.Create(destFileName))
                {
                    using (GZipStream Compress =
                        new GZipStream(outFile,
                        CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        // Copy the source file into 
                        // the compression stream.
                        inFile.CopyTo(Compress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This throws an IOException any time it tries to rotate the log files. I *think* it throws the exception when it tries to write to the .gz file, but I'm not sure.  This is the stack trace:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding, Int32)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.IO.File.AppendText(System.String)
   at XRayDataTransferService.XRayDataTransferService.LogMessage(System.String)
   at XRayDataTransferService.XRayDataTransferService.RunAgent()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Can someone confirm that it is throwing the exception when it tries to write the compressed info to the .gz file, and tell me what about the situation is causing it to throw the exception?

EDIT

This is the LogMessage function.  Most of the time this works, the only time it throws the exception is when the log is rotated.

```
static void LogMessage(string messageText)
    {
        string ErrorLogFileName = @"C:\temp\dataTransferErrorLog.txt";

        using (StreamWriter Log = File.AppendText(ErrorLogFileName))
        {
            try
            {
                Log.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", dateStamp, messageText);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
static void RunAgent()
    {
        while (!shutdown)
        {
            LogMessage("Starting data transfer...");
            errors = 0;

           // Do some data processing

            LogMessage("Finished running with " + errors.ToString() + " error(s).");

            RotateLogs();
        }
        shutdownSignal.Set();
    }
```

I've stated in comments below, but just so it's clear, only one thread is running. This is a service so it has to be in a separate thread, but there is only one thread running.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Add your pdb files to where your code is running and you will get line numbers in the stack trace.

Comment: What logging library you are using (if any)? Is it possible for you to start using NLog?

Comment: It looks like this is not the part of code that is throwing this exception. Otherwise, these methods would be included in the stack trace. Could you post the XRayDataTransferService.XRayDataTransferService.LogMessage(System.String) method?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's with the empty `catch` block?!

Comment: Debugging to see if that's where the exception was coming from.  That's partly why I ruled that function out in the first place.

Comment: Could you post the code where you call LogMessage() method and RotateLogs() method

Comment: @bluesky74656 Check my answer, I'm sure that this is the case, you can solve it easily by passing some string argument to these methods which will modify the filenames according to the service that is logging. the better approach would be to synchronize file access.

Comment: Only one service is writing to that file.  I copy and paste the code into each service and change the file name.

Comment: @bluesky74656 Check the answer now, I found your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** According to your comments, I have tried your code and found the problem that you were having. When you call this line `File.Create(@"C:\temp\dataTransferErrorLog.txt");` it returns the `FileStream` which is never closed. Therefore you can use two approaches. First is that you need to assign that `FileStream` to a variable and explicitly call `Close()` on a `FileStream` like:

```
if (!LogFile.Exists)
{
        Compress(LogFile);
        LogFile.Delete();
        FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\Users\On\Documents\dataTransferErrorLog.txt");
        fs.Close();
}
```

or the better approach is to don't even create the file there because the later call to `File.AppendText()` will create the file it doesn't exist. So I suggest that you make your method `RotateLogs` like this:

```
private static void RotateLogs()
{
    FileInfo LogFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\dataTransferErrorLog.txt");

    if (LogFile.Exists && (LogFile.Length) >= 10 * 1048576)
    {
         Compress(LogFile);
         LogFile.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace the exception is not occurring in this code. In your `LogMessage` function you are calling `AppendText` and that is where it is failing. Add an exception handler at the top of your code (main app entry point) and log (as in, write to a text file directly or to the console, no fancy logging, just get the data) and the details of the exception will give you more information.

As a second suggestion, `log4net` is a really useful logging library. It has a rolling file appender built in. It is easy to configure and set up and available via `NuGet`. You may want to consider using it. Lots of products do.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your pdbs along with your assemblies, and you will get line numbers in the stack trace, which will enable you to pin-point where the exception is being thrown. You do generate pdbs don't you?

Comment: The PDBs are generated, but weren't deployed at the time that stack trace is from.  They are now, but the rate of data accumulation means we won't run into the problem again for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Its not in the Rotation Function.
for me it looks like you are doing the rotation and at the same time you want to append to the file (to write the log) so it crashes.

But post the Exceptions message, this will clear everything up

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to write something in your log with one thread and another thread is trying to rotate the log...

it is enough to change your code so to know better what is happening

```
static void LogMessage(string messageText)
{
    try
    {
        string ErrorLogFileName = @"C:\temp\dataTransferErrorLog.txt";

        using (StreamWriter Log = File.AppendText(ErrorLogFileName))
        {
            Log.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", dateStamp, messageText);
        }
     }
     catch(Exception) { throw; }
}
```

anyway your best choise is to use a robust log library as log4net or NLog.

They do their work pretty good

Comment: This service is not multi-threaded. The reference to ThreadStart is because it is a service and must run in it's own thread, but only one thread is running.

Comment: @bluesky74656 what does it call Rotate()?

Comment: It gets called at the end of the main service execution loop in this service. In other services I've put it at the end of LogMessage with the same result

Comment: @bluesky74656 change your code as in my example and step into the exception or post more code. You are not giving us enough elements. Anyway i'm sure you are doing multithreading wrong

Comment: @bluesky74656 So basically different services are calling these static methods at the same time and they all write to the same file?

Comment: No, I re-use the same code in different services, but each implementation is independent.

Comment: @bluesky74656 if you declare a static method it is not implementation indipendent